# json database get image setting data for json using while loop carousel type jquery json

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json, image

i have an problem where can i get the jquery code for this? i have a database with image i want a jquery like this to output in my website

i will make a slider that will output like that

it will give me a slide that gives me that output i already have a database and php code that is working

[image: australia]

this is an australian government for missing person and our site is like this i want a jquery like this but i don't have the code of the original to do that

missingpersons australia is the link below i can't post here the link because it violate the rules of posting links :D

tried

jquery from search,div,table to output basic jquery don't know advance commands for jquery

tried this link the only problem is the while loop for the data

> [jquerydata](http://demo1.krablekod.ru/agile_carousel/examples/agile_carousel_multiple_slides_visible_example.html)

i edited the carousel the problem is how will i put it?

```
>     <?php
>     include_once('includes/dbConnect.php');
>     
>     
>     ?>
>     <?php
>     
>     $query=mysql_query("select * from persons order by rand()");
>     
>     while($test = mysql_fetch_array($query))  {
>     
>     }
>     
>     
>      ?>
>     [
>     {
>           "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_bike.jpg' alt='Bike'></a><a
> class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
> Part is that...</a></div>",
>           "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>"
>     },
>     {
>           "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_paint.jpg' alt='Paint'></a><a
> class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
> Part is that...</a></div>",
>           "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>"
>     },
>     {
>           "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_bike.jpg' alt='Bike'></a><a
> class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
> Part is that...</a></div>",
>           "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>"
>     },
>     {
>           "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_paint.jpg' alt='Paint'></a><a
> class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
> Part is that...</a></div>",
>           "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>"
>     },
>     {
>           "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_bike.jpg' alt='Bike'></a><a
> class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
> Part is that...</a></div>",
>           "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>"
>     },
>     {
>           "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_paint.jpg' alt='Paint'></a><a
> class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
> Part is that...</a></div>",
>           "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>"
>     },
>     {
>           "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='Penguins.jpg' alt='Tunnel'></a><a
> class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
> Part is that...</a></div>",
>           "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>"
>     },
>     {
>           "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='Penguins.jpg' alt='Tunnel'></a><a
> class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
> Part is that...</a></div>",
>           "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>"
>     }
>     
>     ]
```

here's the query of my image and name

```
>  $query=mysql_query("select * from persons  order by date desc LIMIT
> 0,10 ");
> 
> > <img height=200 width=200 src=' upload/". $test['Image'] ."'/> <a href
> > ='profile.php?PersonID=$id'> ".$test['LastName'].", ". $test['FirstName']." ". $test['MiddleName']."</a>
```

i'm using this while loop for my search 
and it calls correctly.

and here's the json code

```
> <script>
> 
>     $.getJSON("agile_carousel_data.php", function (data) {
> 
>         $("#multiple_slides_visible").agile_carousel({
>             carousel_data: data,
>             carousel_outer_height: 230,
>             carousel_height      : 200,
>             slide_height         : 200,
>             carousel_outer_width : 480,
>             slide_width          : 260,
>             number_slides_visible: 3,
>             transition_time      : 330,
>             control_set_1: "previous_button,next_button",
>             control_set_2: "group_numbered_buttons",
>             persistent_content: "<p class='persistent_content'>Agile Carousel Example: Multiple Slides Visible</p>"
>         });
> 
>     })
> 
>  </script>
```

this is the content of my $data in data.php

```
> `<?php include_once('includes/dbConnect.php'); $data = array(); while
> ($test = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { $data[]['content'] = "<div
> class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo'
> src='{$test['image']}' alt='Bike'></a><a class='caption'
> href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best Part is
> that...</a></div>" $data[]['content_button'] = "<div
> class='thumb'><img src='{$test['thumb']}' alt='bike is
> nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place Holder</p>" } echo
> json_encode($data); ?> `
```

the code above won't give me anything i included my database connection but still nothing
won't output anything here's the link again [link for the original website](http://demo1.krablekod.ru/agile_carousel/examples/agile_carousel_multiple_slides_visible_example.html)

Comment: @Rooster tried table div and jquery ajax but it clones my whole site so the best way i think is that kind of jquery because it is exactly the way i want to show my site

Comment: jquery ajax and div and the most messy i tried is the table tab i use table in while loop to output it like that and it's really messy .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a jquery carousel plugin.
http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/jquery-carousel-plugins/
http://www.webdesigntunes.com/freebies/30-amazing-free-jquery-slider-and-carousel-plugins-of-2013/

Edit: does this help?

```
$data = array();
$x = 0;
while ($test = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[$x]['content'] = "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='{$test['image']}' alt='Bike'></a><a class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best Part is that...</a></div>";
    $data[$x]['content_button'] = "<div class='thumb'><img src='{$test['thumb']}' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place Holder</p>";
$x++;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: already seen that :) the problem is the behavior of the images .

Comment: Can you clarify what you are wanting? Do you want to know how to lay out the images with html and css, or go to next image on click with jquery etc?

Comment: found one the only problem is the while loop for the database

Comment: i have the syntax for json the only problem is json uses `[{ then at the end }, it uses comma as next picture the problem is i can't do it with while loop it won't give output

Comment: tried replacing [ to ] and changing the while loop but won't output anything

Comment: So if you run that PHP file the output is blank? does it give any errors?

Comment: no it don't give errors the screen is just blank sir @micheal

Comment: this is the content of my data.php `<?php
include_once('includes/dbConnect.php');

$data = array();
while ($test = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[]['content'] = "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='{$test['image']}' alt='Bike'></a><a class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best Part is that...</a></div>"
    $data[]['content_button'] = "<div class='thumb'><img src='{$test['thumb']}' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place Holder</p>"
}
echo json_encode($data);
?> `

Comment: updated my code sir @micheal that's the one i put in the data of agile_carousel_data.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34764/discussion-between-michael-lawton-and-ermel-justin-pablo-lopez)

Comment: tried to open it found that it have an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Agile-Carousel-master\examples\agile_carousel_data.php on line 9`